# One JS solution to disable multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

For those who wish to minimize the chances of stealing their web content, various solutions or codes are available to:

1. Disable copy-paste
2. Disable print
3. Disable print screen etc.

I suppose, all of these above use clipboard functionality to be able to function. If we are able to disable clipboard function itself at the outset, all of these three (or even more!) purposes could be achieved in a single script.

Is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible, you can't interfere the clipboard in user's machine, especially outside a browser. The only way to protect your content is never to load it to client-side. And `print` doesn't use the clipboard.

Comment: Not, possible, plus someone could just take a picture, and there's nothing you could do even if you managed to block these things. Try obfuscating your code